# Send command to subprocess.popen()

Tags: python, subprocess, minecraft

## My problem

I need to send a command to a popen process that executes a batch file. I have been searching pretty long in the internet for a solution but didn't find anything. The "command" I have to send to is `stop`.

## Tried solutions

I have already tried it with `.stdin.write()` what ended up in not being able to send commands from the normal console and also the popen process to wait until another execution of the file. Another thing I tried is `.communicate()` which ended up again with the popen process to wait until another execution of the file.

## Current code

Starting code:

```
mcserver = subprocess.Popen('C:/Users/FlexGames/Desktop/Minecraft_Server/FTBTrident-1.4.0-1.7.10Server/ServerStart.bat', 
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Current part to send a command to console:

```
mcserver.stdin.write(b'stop\n')
```

Comment: `write()`ing a command _does_ send it to the process's stdin. Nothing about your code is wrong. Maybe Minecraft doesn't _listen_ on stdin when that stdin isn't attached to a TTY -- perhaps it reads commands direct from the TTY itself -- or maybe something else is wrong, but your Python is fine. If you can build a [mre] that lets others see the problem without needing to have a Minecraft server themselves, that would do a lot to make this answerable by folks with general Python expertise.

Comment: BTW, you might want `\r\n` instead of just `\n` as your newline sequence, since this is a Windows-y platform.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy still didn't send any command

Comment: Unless you used `strace` or a similar tool, you don't know that. Maybe it was sent but not acted on (see f/e my speculation above that minecraft may only be reading commands from stdin if that stdin is connected directly to a terminal); maybe the read end of the FIFO isn't open at all, so the write end is just blocking indefinitely. If you want to be sure, you need to look under the hood. As it is, you're _assuming_ that the Python code is wrong, but you don't have any actual evidence for that unless you ask your operating system which processes are reading, which processes are writing, etc.